# Объясните новичку почему не меняется значение i?

Tags: javascript

```js
const isPowerOfThree = (num) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
    return (Math.pow(3, i)) === num ? true : false;
  }
};


console.log(isPowerOfThree(1));
console.log(isPowerOfThree(5));
console.log(isPowerOfThree(23));
console.log(isPowerOfThree(23));
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < num; i++)` последние данные в скобках, команда увеличить значение

Comment: Потому что до выполнения `i += 1` дело никогда не доходит, `return` выполняется раньше.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, а какая разница между этими двумя записями  `i++ && i += 1`?

Comment: @Air вторая на символ длиннее

Comment: @Kir_Antipov,  смешно....

Comment: @Air, первая возвращает текущее значение а потом увеличивает, а вторая увеличивает и возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде переменная `i` меняется только в одном месте:

```
for (let i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
```

До этого места программа не доходит. Она сначала инициализирует переменную `i = 0`, потом проверяет условие `i < num`, после чего входит в тело условия. Там происходит возврат значения `(return...)`, т.е. ваша функция `isPowerOfThree` возвращает значение и прекращает свою работу.